# How can I get docker to reuse layers using cache_from

Tags: docker, caching, layer

I'm trying to reuse docker layers from a pulled image but somehow cannot seem to get it to work. The minimal Dockerfile I'm using is:

```
FROM alpine
RUN printf "ping localhost &\nsleep infinity" > /run.sh && chmod +x /run.sh
CMD /run.sh
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
```

with the following build steps:

```
docker image rm -f
docker pull docker.io/my-temp
docker build -t test-image --progress=plain --no-cache --cache-from docker.io/my-temp .
docker image inspect test-image
docker tag test-image docker.io/my-image
docker push docker.io/my-image
```

And every time I get different hashes for the two last layers (and the push command doesn't recognize that the layers should exist already). Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?